# objectTabLayout.setupWithViewPager is not found

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments, xml-binding

i am new in android and i am facing an strange situation in which i am not finding the setupWithViewPager.When i am calling objectTabLayout.setupWithViewPager then setupWithViewPager is not finding..what should i do?

My XML Code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@color/colorBlack"
    android:id="@+id/favoriteFragment_RL"
    tools:context="Fragments.Favorite">

   <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:id="@+id/favoriteFragment_TabLayout"
       android:minHeight="?actionBarSize"
       app:tabGravity="fill"
       app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorWhite"
       app:tabIndicatorHeight="4dp"
       app:tabBackground="@color/colorPrimary"
       app:tabMode="fixed"
       app:tabTextColor="@color/colorWhite"/>
    
    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/favoriteFragment_viewPager"
        android:layout_below="@id/favoriteFragment_TabLayout"/>


</RelativeLayout>

my java code

     package Fragments;

import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.connectsocialmediaapp.R;

import AdapterClasses.FavoriteStatusTabAdapter;


public class Favorite extends Fragment {


    //XML Variables
    private View parent;
    private TableLayout objectTablayout;
    private ViewPager objectViewPager;

    //Class Variables
    favoriteImageStatusFragment objectFavoriteImageStatusFragment;
    FavoriteStatusTabAdapter objectFavoriteStatusTabAdapter;
    favoriteTextStatusFragment objectFavoriteTextStatusFragment;

    private int[] tabIcons= {
            R.drawable.ic_text, R.drawable.ic_image
    };
    public Favorite() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        parent= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_favorite, container, false);
        initializeVariables();
        return parent;
    }

    private void addFragmentToTablayout()
    {
    try
    {
        objectFavoriteStatusTabAdapter=new FavoriteStatusTabAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
        objectFavoriteStatusTabAdapter.addFragments(objectFavoriteTextStatusFragment);

        objectFavoriteStatusTabAdapter.addFragments(objectFavoriteImageStatusFragment);
        objectViewPager.setAdapter(objectFavoriteStatusTabAdapter);


        objectTablayout.(objectViewPager);
        objectViewPager.setSaveFromParentEnabled(false);

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    }


    private void initializeVariables()
    {
        try
        {
            objectFavoriteTextStatusFragment=new favoriteTextStatusFragment();
            objectFavoriteImageStatusFragment=new favoriteImageStatusFragment();

            objectTablayout=parent.findViewById(R.id.favoriteFragment_TabLayout);

            objectViewPager=parent.findViewById(R.id.favoriteFragment_viewPager);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            
        }
    }
}
```

is there any alternative way to access setupWithViewPager or how should i access it.

Comment: Pls provide a reproducible code

Comment: i have added dear please see

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are confusing xml using TabLayout and Java code you use TableLayout.
Modify TableLayoutOut in Java Code and Running, your problem has been solved

```
public class Favorite extends Fragment {


//XML Variables
private View parent;
private TabLayout objectTablayout;
private ViewPager objectViewPager;

//Class Variables
favoriteImageStatusFragment objectFavoriteImageStatusFragment;
FavoriteStatusTabAdapter objectFavoriteStatusTabAdapter;
favoriteTextStatusFragment objectFavoriteTextStatusFragment;

private int[] tabIcons= {
        R.drawable.ic_text, R.drawable.ic_image
};
public Favorite() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    parent= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_favorite, container, false);
    initializeVariables();
    return parent;
}

private void addFragmentToTablayout()
{
try
{
    objectFavoriteStatusTabAdapter=new FavoriteStatusTabAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
    objectFavoriteStatusTabAdapter.addFragments(objectFavoriteTextStatusFragment);

    objectFavoriteStatusTabAdapter.addFragments(objectFavoriteImageStatusFragment);
    objectViewPager.setAdapter(objectFavoriteStatusTabAdapter);


    objectTablayout.(objectViewPager);
    objectViewPager.setSaveFromParentEnabled(false);

}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Toast.makeText(getContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}


private void initializeVariables()
{
    try
    {
        objectFavoriteTextStatusFragment=new favoriteTextStatusFragment();
        objectFavoriteImageStatusFragment=new favoriteImageStatusFragment();

        objectTablayout=parent.findViewById(R.id.favoriteFragment_TabLayout);

        objectViewPager=parent.findViewById(R.id.favoriteFragment_viewPager);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        
    }
}
```

}